# Scrapy stopping pagination on condition?

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

So I want to scrape articles from a site that has pagination. Basically, every page is a list of article links and the spider follows the links on the page in a `parse_article` method, as well as following the successive next page links. However, is there a way to make this stop after a given number of articles are scraped? For example, this is what I have so far using a `crawlspider`:

```
rules = (

    #next page rule: 
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='next']"),follow=True)

    #Extract all internal links which follows this regex:
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('REGEXHERE',),deny=()),callback='parse_article'),
)

def parse_article(self, response):
    #do parsing stuff here
```

I want to stop following the next page once I've parsed 150 articles. It doesn't matter if I scrape a little more than 150, I just want to stop going to the next page once I've hit that number. Is there any way to do that? Something like having a counter in the `parse_article` method? Just new to `scrapy` so I'm not sure what to try.... I looked into [depth_limit](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit), but I'm not so sure that's what I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve that by setting:

[CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-itemcount) = 150

In your project settings.

If you have multiple Spiders in your project and just want a particular one to be affected by this setting, set it in **custom_settings** class variable:

```
custom_settings = { 'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 150 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, with a project with multiple spiders, is it possible to make this `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` only apply to one spider?

Comment: @ocean800 I've updated my answer. Please try and let me know if it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

The approach I take on my spiders is to actually have a donescraping flag and I check it first thing in each of my parse_* functions and return an empty list for the results.

This adds the graceful behavior of allowing items and urls already in the download queue to finish happening while not fetching any MORE items.

I've never used CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT so I dont' know if that "gracefully" closes the spider.  I expect it does not

At the beginning of every parse function:

```
#early exit if done scraping
    if self.donescraping:
        return None
```

Comment: In some cases you might need to `return []` depending on the parse function. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just trying to understand more-- how exactly is the spider closed here? I don't understand how returning `None`/`[]` response in the parse function would stop a `CrawlSpider`/`LinkExtractor` from crawling more links?

Comment: When the spider runs out of stuff in the download queue, it closes on its own.  What my solution does is to let it gracefully close without farming more items, after it finishes processing the currently collected items, as opposed to quitting immediately.